# Tensorflow 1.15 + CUDA + cuDNN installation using Conda

Tags: tensorflow, conda, miniconda

I am trying to install tensorflow-gpu 1.15 using Conda for an easy install of CUDA and cuDNN. The problem is that checking the [compatibility chart](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#configuration_options) of the official web I need python 3.6, CUDA 10.0 and cuDNN 7.4.

Searching the Conda rep via `conda search cudnn` it says that there isn't cuDNN 7.4. Is there any other way to install the required packages? Or maybe tensorflow 1.15 also works with other combinations of versions?

As a side note, python 3.6, tensorflow-gpu 1.15 and CUDA 10 install correctly, but it seems I can't use the GPU correctly without cuDNN.
I just recently started using Conda, so maybe there is a straight forward way to do this that I don't realize. My Conda version is 4.9.1 (miniconda version).

---update---

Just in case I add the error while trying `conda create -n myenv -c conda-forge tensorflow-gpu=1.15`:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: - 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package _tflow_select conflicts for:
_tflow_select==2.1.0=gpu
tensorflow==1.15.0 -> _tflow_select[version='2.1.0|2.3.0|2.2.0',build='gpu|mkl|eigen']
Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am not sure if that is the problem, but I installed the following way

```
conda create -n tensorflow1.15 python=3.5
conda activate tensorflow1.15
conda install cudatoolkit=10.0
conda install cudnn=7.3.1
pip3 install tensorflow-gpu==1.15
```

And it seems to works perfectly with the GPU. I didn't know that cuDNN 7.3.1 worked like 7.4. The best way is to install tensorflow with conda, but it give me an error of trying to install tensorflow-gpu=2.X.

Also maybe it's interesting to say that you can search CUDA and similar official installers with `conda search -c nvidia <packageName>`.

Comment: The above installation steps give you errors while training a model with deeplabv3
The error is "failed-to-get-convolution-algorithm-this-is-probably-because-cudnn-failed"
This happens when cudnn is not compatible .
Update with 
```
conda create -n tensorflow1.15 python=3.5
conda activate tensorflow1.15
conda install cudatoolkit=10.0
conda install cudnn=7.6.0
pip3 install tensorflow-gpu==1.15

```

Answer (score 7):

I would let `conda` handle all the dependencies itself by installing tensorflow via `conda`, not `pip`. The GPU version of tensorflow is available e.g. in the popular `conda-forge` channel:

```
conda create -n myenv -c conda-forge tensorflow-gpu=1.15
```

Comment: I tried that but it pop `UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other`. Maybe it's my OS? I'm on Ubuntu 20 LTS. I also heard that some users had problems with python 3.6

Comment: Mmh, weird. I just tried on Ubuntu 20.04 and it worked here. Did you type the exact same command line as above?

Comment: You may want to give another python version if for some reason your conda proposes to install 3.6, for example `conda create -n myenv -c conda-forge tensorflow-gpu=1.15 python=3.7`.

Comment: Oh, thx. I added the exact error in the question just in case it is easy to solve. I tried also adding python=3.5 or python=3.7 but it outputs the same error.

Comment: `channels`: `conda-forge` and `defaults`

Answer (score 3):

The best setup for TensorFlow 1.15 is to follow this guide here:
https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/tensorflow-1.14/install.html#tf-install.

Recommended versions are **CUDA 10.0** and **cudNN 7.6.5**

**Attention** to the protobuf version which will be installed, if you execute the gpu version it's **protobuf 4.21.1**, but you have to rewrite it with the command:

`pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==1.15 "protobuf<4.0"`

If you use the CPU version it's recommended to use this version here:(https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.4.0) to avoid errors. Just download the protoc-3.4.0-win32.zip (windows)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If I can spare anyone a headache here is what worked for me (for **tensorflow 1.15.5**)
For recent GPU (30/40 Nvidia series) You can't install tensorflow-gpu=1.15 from the conda forge channel. To do so you need to :

- [Download](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/miniconda/) and Install miniconda/Anaconda on your linux machine in order to facilitate the install of cuda and cudnn libs
- Follow [aurelie-navir answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64820487/14503275) (I use python 3.8 for compatibility)

```
conda create -n tensorflow1.15_nvidia python=3.8.18
conda activate tensorflow1.15_nvidia
conda install cudatoolkit=10.0
conda install cudnn=7.3.1
```

- Now you need to add nvidia-pyindex channel to your pip setup in order to download the official [Nvidia Tensorflow 1.x project](https://github.com/NVIDIA/tensorflow#install)

```
pip install --user nvidia-pyindex
pip install --user nvidia-tensorflow[horovod]
```

This should do the trick :)